# logical indexing into cell array to remove rows

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array and I am looking to remove some of the rows.

If a company in my cell array is not in companies_list I would like to remove the row from my cell array. I have tried the below however I get the error message:

> Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

Here is my code:

```
 indx = ismember(mycell.companies(:,1), companies_list(:,1));
 companies = mycell.companies(mycell.companies(indx == 1), :);
```

Comment: Convert both of them to double arrays with `cell2mat` and then try `ismember` again?

Comment: my cell array contains text and numbers in different fields - would cell2mat still work in that case?

Comment: So, even the first columns have such mixed datatypes? I meant using `cell2mat` just on the first columns - `cell2mat(mycell.companies(:,1))`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. mycell.companies is a 4500 x 2 cell. Both fields are text.

Comment: Tried `cell2mat` just on the first columns of those two cell arrays?

Comment: Its the 2nd line where the error happens. Why would I need to do cell2mat on companies_list?

Comment: Isn't `companies_list` a cell array too? And what's the error?

Comment: yes it is. However the ismember function give me the correct logical array. Its trying to use 'indx' where the error happens

Comment: If you have the correct `indx`, after that just do this - `companies = mycell.companies(indx, :);`

Comment: ah yep was being bit stupid there. thanks again

Comment: Great! Problem solved and we move on :)